# Finding all $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})\cap C^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $c\in\mathbb{R}$ so $f'(x)=f(x+c)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-transform

If we apply the Fourier Transform to our equation we get
$$ix\hat{f}(x)=e^{icx}\hat{f}(x)$$
So, if $f\neq 0$ we conclude $ix=e^{icx}$. Plugging $x=1$ we get $c=-i\ln(i)=\frac{\pi}{2}$. But putting this value in the last equation we get $ix=e^{-ln(i)x}$, which only works for a specific values of $x$. I am at a loss, does this implies that the only solution is $f=0$?

Answer (score 2):

From $ix\hat{f}(x)=e^{icx}\hat{f}(x)$ we conclude that the support of $\hat{f}$ is contained in the zero-set $Z := \{x \in \mathbb C\;|\; ix=e^{icx}\}$.  This is a countable discrete set in $\mathbb C$.  But note that for some functions $f$ it can turn out that the distribution $\hat{f}$ has discrete support.  For example, if $f$ is the constant $1$, then $\hat{f} = \delta/(2\pi)$, the Dirac delta, with support $\{0\}$.

Here is one example of a solution:
$$
 f(x) = {{\rm e}^{ 0.3181315052\,x}}\cos \left(  1.337235701\,x
 \right)
$$
satisfies  $f'(x) = f(x+1)$.

The support of its Fourier transform is two solutions $z_1,z_2$ of
$ix = e^{ix}$, given by $z_1 = -1.337235701 - i 0.3181315052,
z_2 = +1.337235701 - i 0.3181315052$.

Of course a Fourier transform cannot have discrete support if $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})\cap C^1(\mathbb{R})$.